# How can I get iOS Placeholder JS text to clear out when field is pre-populated?

Tags: javascript, forms, text, field, placeholder

I'm using this script: https://github.com/domchristie/ios-placeholder to get cross-browser iOS-style placeholder text on a form.

I'm experiencing a problem when I try to pre-populate the field through javascript with a variable from the URL, though. Because no physical keys are being pressed in the field to activate the removal of the placeholder text, both the pre-populated text and the placeholder text are present:

http://mattbyrd.com/test/test.html?Name_First=Matt

Does anyone know any good workaround for that? Or an alternate way to accomplish the placeholder text across browsers?

Thanks! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Matt

Answer (score 0):

You can use placeholder attribut which works well with iOS, and add this small fix to make it work with every browser :
http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html

```
<input type="text" placeholder="my text" ... />
```